# python - access list element by key

Tags: python

If I have the following structure:

```
[
    {'id' : 100, 'name' : 'Bill'},
    {'id' : 100, 'name' : 'Dave'}
]
```

How can I get an element by the 'name' key.  That is, I want to get `{'id' : 100, 'name' : 'Dave'}`but without having to iterate and check each for a match.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: You have to iterate. There's no mapping between names and dictionary objects here.

Comment: You're using the wrong data-structure then, you've to iterate to find an item in list.

Comment: Is there an alternative data structure this can be mapped to?  I am receiving this structure from an api and will be doing this operation a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first transform your list of dictionaries into a single dictionary with "name" as the key:

```
data = {x['name']: x for x in original_data}
```

Then you use:

```
data['Dave']
data['Bill']
```

PS:
For Python older than 2.7, use this:

```
data = dict((x['name'], x) for x in original_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
[x for x in a if x['name']=='Dave']
```

But here you are iterating over the list and checking each item. Actually, there's no way to do such a thing without iterating over the list, because it's a `list` and not a `map`.